# C#: Is there a way to SET the selected index of an item in listview at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

C#: Is there a way to SET the selected index of an item in listview at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the [item in the collection you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx) selected and [set its public property Selected = true.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.selected.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
listView.SelectedIndices.Clear();
listView.SelectedIndices.Add(someIndex);
```