# Selecting an item in the list view programatically

Tags: c#, listview

I have a list view in windows forms. `_listView1`.
I wish to programatically select an item in the listview.
I say `_listView1.Items[i].Select=true;`

But that doesn't solve the problem. The item doesn't get selected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select an item in a ListView programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791235/how-to-select-an-item-in-a-listview-programmatically)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Is there a way to SET the selected index of an item in listview at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817309/c-is-there-a-way-to-set-the-selected-index-of-an-item-in-listview-at-runtime)

Comment: Thanks for the replies Soner Gonul, TwoMore and user2025312. The Select was a typo. Apologies. I had "Selected" in my code.And I tried the steps mentioned in the links specified for no luck and then posted this question.

Answer (score 3):

The property is [`Selected`, not `Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.selected.aspx):

```
_listView1.Items[i].Selected = true;
```

Comment: Thanks Grant Thomas. Select was a typo. I had used Selected only and the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
_listView1.selectedIndex = i;

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`ListViewItem.Selected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.selected.aspx) property;

```
_listView1.Items[i].Selected = true;
```

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the item is selected.